# Order by nodes that received more relationships in a certain period of time

Tags: neo4j, cypher, cypher-3.1

Is it possible to order by nodes that received more relationships in a certain period of time?

For example, I have User and Movie, and a User can LIKE a Movie. The LIKE relationship has a property called `date`, which is the moment the user liked the product.

What I want is: the Products that received more LIKE in the last 2 days.

How can I do it? :)

Comment: How are you storing the dates in the database?

Comment: In this format: `2017-10-08T16:49:54.398Z`

Comment: Ok, so I believe the query posted in my answer will works. Please, take a look! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are storing dates as strings like `"2017-09-02 00:00:00"`. So in this case I believe you can try something like:

```
MATCH (:User)-[like:LIKE]->(movie:Movie)
WHERE like.date > "date from 2 days ago"
RETURN movie, count(like) as numberOfLikes
ORDER BY numberOfLikes DESC
```

Comment: I only changed the the MATCH part to `MATCH(movie:Movie)<-[like:LIKED]-()` e funcionou. Obrigado! :D